# PiKVM update: /usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4356-sdio.AP6356S.txt exists in filesystem

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, pacman, firmware

When I try to run `pacman -Syu` on my PiKVM, I'm getting

```
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
linux-firmware-pikvm: /usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4356-sdio.AP6356S.txt exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://discord.com/channels/580094191938437144/896216359963332628/1035603300692807690), just delete the file and try again,

```
su -
rw
rm  /usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4356-sdio.AP6356S.txt
pacman -Syu
reboot
```